# Pods not installing properly

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcconfig

I had been installing pods and the pods get installed properly . However , in the Project navigator , the .xcconfig files are red in color and I cannot set the same in the project-> info -> configurations either as they don't get listed and only none is listed. When debugged , I could find that the .xcconfig files were getting accessed by the xcode in the following path

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxxxx/app/Pods/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-broadcastuploadSetupUI/Pods-broadcastuploadSetupUI.release.xcconfig
```

/Pods is there twice , Because of which I am getting the following errors :

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I am working with Xcode 9 beta . Can anyone kindly help ?

P.S , I have tried sudo gem install , pod update , disintegrate , install and everything that is available on the internet as a solution. I'd be glad if anyone could help

This is my podfile :

```
#platform :ios, ‘11.0’
source 'https://URL_TO_ACCESS_PODSPEC_FOR_POD'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


target 'app' do
pod 'objective-zip', '~> 1.0'
pod 'AssistScreenShareKit'
use_frameworks!
end

target ‘broadcastupload’ do
    pod 'AssistScreenShareKit'
use_frameworks!
end

target ‘broadcastuploadSetupUI' do
pod 'AssistScreenShareKit'
use_frameworks!
end
```

Error :

```
The file “Pods-app.release.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxx/app/Pods/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-app/Pods-app.release.xcconfig)
```

Comment: delete your workspace, pod lock, pod file, pod folder, derived data  then again init the pod file and reinstall it --clean, build and run.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: I tried , but unfortunately , no success ! :/

Comment: I have added my podfile for further clarification

Comment: This maybe stupid, but did your tried to re-launch Xcode after `pod install` ?

Comment: I quit XCode completely and relaunched it after pod install !

Comment: its workspace or xocde project ? pls open workspace

Comment: It is workspace. I have mentioned that I have tried almost all the solutions available on the internet.

Comment: set your minimum os target 9.0 and reinstall it

Comment: minimum target as 9 ? How does that even matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install pod

1. Open a terminal window, and $ cd into your project directory.
2. To create a Podfile you need to to run `$ pod init.`
3. Open your Podfile. The first line should specify the platform and
   version supported.

> ```
>  platform :ios, '9.0'
>
>  use_frameworks! target 'yourProjectName' do
>      pod 'Alamofire' end
> ```

4. Then install the pod

> `pod install`

Comment: did you check if your code requires Convert to Current Swift Syntax under Edit.

Answer (score 0):

First delete all pods and `Podfile.lock`

1. open terminal and go to folder path
2. Edit your podfile by this

   `platform :ios, '8.0'
    use_frameworks!
    target 'MyApp' do
      //add your all pods
   end`
3. `pod install`
4. close xcode and open `MyApp.xcworkspace` file

check for more: [Command-line Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#group_installation)

This will help you.

Comment: can you please remove `source 'https://URL_TO_ACCESS_PODSPEC_FOR_POD'`  
`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` this line

Comment: This is not a pod which has its podspec file in the Cocopods. It is a locally mentioned pod and so It has to be there to identify the podspec file

Answer (score 0):

update your Cocoapods version, I had this problem with Cocoapods 1.5.3 and it was fixed in 1.6.1

to do that open terminal and just type 
`gem install cocoapods`